# Writing new line character in file

Tags: c++, string, text, win32gui

I just want write blank line into the file. i use following code but is not working.

```
        char* RegID;
        RegID = "10";
        char* mndtime;
        mndtime  = "10";
        char* resourcetype;
        resourcetype  = "Backup";
        char* ressubtype;
        ressubtype = "shadowprotect";
        char* DataBuffer = new char[100];

        StrCpy(DataBuffer,"<wpshadowprotectstatus>");
        strcat(DataBuffer,"\n");
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<mndtime>");
        strcat(DataBuffer,RegID);
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<\\mndtime>\n");
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<resourcetype>");
        strcat(DataBuffer,RegID);
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<\\resourcetype>\n");
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<ressubtype>");
        strcat(DataBuffer,RegID);
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<\\ressubtype>\n");
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<jobname>");
        strcat(DataBuffer,RegID);
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<\\jobname>\n");
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<jobstarttime>");
        strcat(DataBuffer,RegID);
        strcat(DataBuffer,"<\\jobstarttime>\n");
        HANDLE hFile; 

        hFile = CreateFile("text.txt",                // name of the write
                           GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                           0,                      // do not share
                           NULL,                   // default security
                           CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
                           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                           NULL);                  // no attr. template

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        { 
            return 0;
        }
        DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
        BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;
        bErrorFlag = WriteFile(hFile,           // open file handle
                        DataBuffer,      // start of data to write
                        dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                        &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                        NULL);            // no overlapped structure
```

but i dont known why new line is not dump in text file.

Note :- 
1)I dont want to use std:: library c++.
2)Dont want to use xml parser.

Comment: As an aside .. don't you mean  strcat(DataBuffer,"</jobstarttime>\n");

Comment: What do you get in the text file?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are using `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` to create and write the file. This will avoid the automatic translation from `'\n'` to `"\r\n"` that the C runtime library does for you. You are most likely getting a newline `'\n'` alone, which means that the one line of text is followed by the next one immediately below to the right.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't your real code since you allocate space for 100 characters but it looks like you're writing around 160.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\r\n` for line breaks on Windows.

And your XML is malformed.  XML closing tags use the `/` character, not the `\` character.  And you are writing the same `RegID` variable for all of the XML values instead of using your other variables (`mndtime`, `resourcetype`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Windows?
If so, replace \n with \r\n. For FILE* / iostream it is done automatically by runtime, but not for WriteFile.
And, of course, you need two line endings to get blank line.

BTW, generating long string with strcat has O(N^2) complexity, which is very bad.

Comment: It's not just the O(N^2) complexity which makes it bad.  It's the fact that it does no checks with regards to the buffer length, and thus easily results in buffer overflow.